# How to make Mockito do something every time the method on the mock is called?

Tags: testing, methods, mockito

I'm trying to  achieve this behavior with Mockito:

When object of type O is applied to a method M, the mock should execute another method on  the object of type O passing itself as a parameter.

Is it possible after all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can probably use some combination of `doAnswer` and the `when` combined with `Mockito.any`.  `doAnswer` is a part of [PowerMockito](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html), which helps extend a lot of the mocking you may want to do.

NOTE, `doAnswer` is used as an example for void functions.  For a non-void you can use your standard `Mockito.when(MOCK.call).then(RESULT)`

```
PowerMockito.doAnswer(new org.mockito.stubbing.Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        //Do whatever to Object O here.
        return null;
    }).when(MOCKOBJECT.methodCall(Mockito.any(O.class)));
```

This then does the helpful `doAnswer` functionality on a mock object, and using the `when` you can assign it to catch for any specific class of object (instead of having to specify an exact object it should be expecting).  Using the `Mockito.any(Class.class))` as part of the parameters lets Mockito know to fire off your doWhatever, when it hits a method call with ANY object of the specified type passed in.

Comment: You don't need PowerMockito for this, you can just write when(MOCKOBJECT.methodCall(any(O.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<...>() { ... });

Comment: Good catch, it's tricky sometimes to pull out examples cleanly because all my mock tests are just an amalgm of calls for static/non-static calls.

Comment: Don't use PowerMockito.  As far as I can see, there's no need for it here.  Mockito has a `doAnswer` method, which does precisely what you need.  The solution given here (except with `Mockito.doAnswer` instead of `PowerMockito.doAnswer`) should work fine for you; if it doesn't, check the Mockito documentation for `doAnswer`.  The solution given by Tavian, using `when` and `thenAnswer` will work too, if the method that you want to stub is not void.

Comment: `doAnswer()` is part of mockito-core-1.10.19.jar, no need to use PowerMockito